# Python pandas: add new columns based on the existed a column value, and set the value of new columns as 1 or 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named df as following:

```
ticker        class_n  
  1              a
  2              b
  3              c
  4              d
  5              e
  6              f
  7              a
  8              b
  ............................
```

I want to add new columns to this dataframe, the new columns names is the value of unique category of class_n(I mean no repeat class_n). Further, the value of new columns is 1 (if the value of class_n is same with column name), other is 0.
for example as the following dataframe. I want to get the new dataframe as following:

```
ticer  class_n   a     b    c   d   e    f   
  1       a      1     0    0   0   0    0
  2       b      0     1    0   0   0    0
  3       c      0     0    1   0   0    0
  4       d      0     0    0   1   0    0    
  5       e      0     0    0   0   1    0
  6       f      0     0    0   0   0    1
  7       a      1     0    0   0   0    0 
  8       b      0     1    0   0   0    0
```

My code is following:

```
lst_class = list(set(list(df['class_n'])))
for cla in lst_class:
    df[c] = 0
    df.loc[df['class_n'] is cla, cla] =1
```

but there is error:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.get_dummies`

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.class_n))

   ticker class_n  a  b  c  d  e  f
0       1       a  1  0  0  0  0  0
1       2       b  0  1  0  0  0  0
2       3       c  0  0  1  0  0  0
3       4       d  0  0  0  1  0  0
4       5       e  0  0  0  0  1  0
5       6       f  0  0  0  0  0  1
6       7       a  1  0  0  0  0  0
7       8       b  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Or the same thing but a little more manually

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.class_n.values)
d = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(u.size, dtype=int)[f], df.index, u)
df.join(d)

   ticker class_n  a  b  c  d  e  f
0       1       a  1  0  0  0  0  0
1       2       b  0  1  0  0  0  0
2       3       c  0  0  1  0  0  0
3       4       d  0  0  0  1  0  0
4       5       e  0  0  0  0  1  0
5       6       f  0  0  0  0  0  1
6       7       a  1  0  0  0  0  0
7       8       b  0  1  0  0  0  0
```